# What's the meaning of "pillage and plunder"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the last episode of "Once Upon a Time" (S04E04 - The Apprentice) there was this dialog:

> Girl: Well, I don't pillage and plunder on the first date, just so you know.
>   Man: Well, that's because you haven't been out with me yet.

I didn't understand meaning of this phrase: "I don't pillage and plunder on the first date"

I searched google but can't find anything related to this context.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Just look up the words one at a time. Good luck.

Comment: @Kris I get the feeling that the words are not to be taken literally in this expression.

Comment: @200 Of course, but here it's close enough.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. A list of these references can be found here: [List of general references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/). Please take a few minutes to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: I am sure @medica's intention is not to humiliate but rather to teach the proper use of the site.  A general reference would be [pillage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pillage) and [plunder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plunder).  You might also be interested in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/distinction-between-pillage-and-plunder).  If there's something about the straightforward definition you do not understand, you can add that to your question.

Comment: @Lynn thank you but I was already looked these links. But I couldn't fit them into this **context**

Comment: @shizlue - Having not seen the show, it is difficult for me to speculate based solely on one line of dialogue.  One would not normally find pillage/plunder in the same train of thought as dating.  Are they pirates?  Are they going to rob someone?  That is where expanding your question to include a bit more information about what was going on, what research you've done, and why you're still confused would be helpful.

Comment: This is verging on asking about the interpretation of literary metaphor. **It has nothing whatsoever to do with English.**  You have to figure out the metaphor on your own.

Comment: Vikings and pirates were infamous for their plundering and pillaging while invading the shores of England. These acts were usually accompanied with rapings. Hence in the collective imagination "pillage and plunder" is often associated with forced intercourse/rape/wild wanton sex depending on your frame of mind and sensitivity.

Comment: pillage is how you get plunder.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I wish to use my first sentence to apologize for the rather unfriendly comments from certain users on this site, to which I, at least, bid you welcome. The phrase **pillage and plunder** has to my knowledge no special, idiomatic meaning that would fit here. I think that is your answer. However, in the present context, the most reasonable interpretation seems to me to be that the girl will not have sex on the first date: a metaphor.

Comment: Perhaps an immediate understanding of this metaphor jumps more quickly to the mind of  someone who sees the underlying shared and extended meaning in *raptō/raptāre/raptāvī/raptātum* than it does to those who do not, *rapists* and *raptors* not being so far off in origin.

Comment: The Man's response: "Well, that's because you haven't been out with me yet." clearly indicates his pirate role to steal her treasure.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, that is a good point. From *rapio*. Feel free to add that to my answer if you're in the mood.

Comment: Sorry. You already noted it's no idiom, at least not in this case. That leaves litcrit, which is what you presented -- but is off-topic.

Comment: Laying bare, short of pillage, the author's deft constructions in public is not much about language or its usage -- there's literary technique that's beyond language.

Comment: @Kris: No: the question whether or not this is idiomatic is a valid question with a clear answer. (As to "literary criticism", this is not about literature anyway, nor is it criticism.)